# android game - lock_layer timed out

Tags: android, canvas

I'm developing a (scroll) game and i'm getting weird messages in LogCat:

- lock_layer() timed out but didn't appear to need to be locked and we recovered(..)
- lock_layer timed out (is the CPU pegged?)...
- executeScheduledBrodcasts() skipped, contention on the client. We'll try again later.

it looks like the rendering takes too long and causes the warning (i'm drawing ~ 50 images every frame), but is this the emulator fault? When i test it on a device (sony ericsson xperia x8), running 1.6, i don't see any lag or any performance drops (i get ~ 60fps).
I get this warning only in android 1.6.

Should i ignore it? Could it cause the game to crash? Am i doing something horribly wrong or is it a bug?

Run code:

```
  while(running) {
    try {
       c = holder.lockCanvas(null);
       synchronized(holder) {
           // getElements - returns a Vector of elements to be drawn relative to camera
           elements = collection.getElements(cameraX,cameraY,cameraWidth,cameraHeight);
           for(int i =0 ; i < elements.size(); i++) {
              // draw the element according to camera
              c.drawBitmap(image,elements.get(i).x,elements.get(i).y);
           }
       }    

    } finally {
       holder.unloackCanvasAndPost(c);
    }
```

}

Thanks for the reply's.

Regards, J.

Comment: This appears in my logcat messages too. And also, apparently, to these guys: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2052

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I know why it is happening. Apparently this occurs when two different threads try and access the canvas. Just [read this thread](http://www.anddev.org/view-layout-resource-problems-f27/warn-surfaceflinger-49-executescheduledbroadcasts-skippe-t4959.html) to know more.

Comment: hmm could u explain a bit more? I have a SurfaceView and inside it a Thread which does the drawing and obtains the canvas from the SurfaceHolder and thats it. I dont have 2 threads.. Did u figure out how to go around this problem?

Comment: It happens whenever two different parts of your code try and get the canvas at the same time. Have a look at when Android will be grabbing the canvas and when you grab it from the surface holder and see if there may be contention. I resolved those issues and now i do not see the error anymore.

Comment: that's just the thing, i have only 1 part of the code the which grabs the canvas nothing else, thats why i dont understand which code is getting the canvas.. could u explain u're work around. thanks